# TypeError: object of type 'IndirectObject' has no len()

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm trying to get contents in pdf file using the python PyPDF2 package. But getting this error.

TypeError: object of type 'IndirectObject' has no len()

This is happening to a particular file. It's working fine with the remaining files. Is there any reasonable logic behind it? [image: Here]
attached more details of the error

Comment: Without the PDF, it's almost impossible to figure out what was happening. My best hint is to upgrade PyPDF2 (there were a couple of new versions recently - maybe the bug was fixed meanwhile).

Comment: Without your actual code it's also unnecessarily hard to debug (e.g. did you use `strict=False` in the PdfFileReader?)